# What function to use to compare different zero values to treatments from same individual?

Tags: r

Subjects have gone through treatment A,B,C. Between each treatment they had a zero week; 0, A, 0, B, 0, C. I would like to compare the answer from question q1 between the first week 0 and week A, the second week 0 and week B, the third week 0 and week C. Does anyone have suggestion of code to use? Appreciate help! :)

```
  id trt q1
 504   0 45
 504   A 56
 504   0 43
 504   B 78
 504   0 34
 504   C 89
 509   0 34
 509   A 56
 509   0 45 
 509   B 67
 509   0 46
 509   C 68
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Define *compare*

Comment: I have tried to compare each treatment with an average of the weeks with 0. Example id 504 (45+43+34)/3, compared to trt A/B/C. I used lmer:  xxxnoll <- xxx[xxx$trt==0,]            meanBL <- tapply(xxxnoll[,i], xxxnoll$id, mean, na.rm=TRUE)   But now I want to test if there is any different if I compare each week with treatment (A,B,C) with the previous week (0). This will indicate if the subjects have a stable baseline value and if there is any cross over effect from treatments.

Comment: can you update your post with actual numbers of expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

An idea to check the percentage differences can be,

```
library(dplyr)

dd %>% 
 group_by(id, grp = rep(seq(1, n() / 2), each = 2)) %>% 
 summarise(new = paste0(round(100*diff(q1) / sum(q1), 1), '%'), 
           comb = paste(trt, collapse = '_')) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 select(-grp)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 3
>      id new   comb 
>   <int> <chr> <chr>
> 1   504 10.9% 0_A  
> 2   504 28.9% 0_B  
> 3   504 44.7% 0_C  
> 4   509 24.4% 0_A  
> 5   509 19.6% 0_B  
> 6   509 19.3% 0_C
> ```